# Nginx RTMP Module is not saving live-streaming files

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, rtmp, live-streaming

I have had no issues in live-streaming to the server, but I am trying to add VOD functionality with some difficulty.  The record_path "/mnt/film/" is not being created or written to by the server, even if I create the directory before running the server.

I have tried adding a user with root permissions, but this did not seem to help.  The weird thing is that error logs are not being created as well, but it writes to the "/mnt/hls" path with no problems whatsoever.

```
user nginx root;
worker_processes  auto;
error_log logs/error.log debug;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

# RTMP configuration
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;

        application live {
            live on;
            # Turn on HLS
            hls on;
            hls_path /mnt/hls/;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
            # record stream to folder /film/
            record all;
            record_path /mnt/film/;
            # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
            deny play all;
        }
    }
}

http {
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 8080;

        location /hls {
            # Disable cache
            add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

            # CORS setup
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

            # allow CORS preflight requests
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }

            types {
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }

            root /mnt/;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 8384;

        # vod caches
        vod_metadata_cache metadata_cache 256m;
        vod_response_cache response_cache 128m;

        # vod settings
        vod_mode local;
        vod_segment_duration 2000; # 2s
        vod_align_segments_to_key_frames on;

        #file handle caching / aio
        open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=5m;
        open_file_cache_valid 2m;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
        open_file_cache_errors on;
        aio on;

        location /vod/ {
            alias mnt/film/;
            vod hls;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Server,range,Content-Length,Content-Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            expires 100d;
        }
    }
}
```

I am just trying to get some files to show up in the "record_path" directory defined in the nginx.conf above.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked `hls_cleanup` directive ? By default the feature is on. In this mode nginx cache manager process removes old HLS fragments and playlists from HLS directory.

https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#hls_cleanup

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I managed to temporarily solve this problem by using ```chmod 777``` on each folder that nginx has to access.  I know this is bad practice, but when I was playing around with creating a user and adding it to groups I was having troubles getting it to grant permissions.  I am sure this is due to inexperience.  However, it seems that the vod-module is not working with my current nginx.conf setup, so I will have to look into that.